# Pattern matching with multiple nonspace characters

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching, wildcard

I have the following string data:

```
data = "*****''[[dogs and cats]]''/n"
```

I would like to use regular expressions in python to extract the string. All the data is encapsuled in the double quotes " ". What are the wildcards that I use so I can get the following:

```
print data.groups(1)
print data.groups(2)
print data.groups(3)

'dogs'
'and'
'cats'
```

Edit: So far I have something a long the lines of this

```
  test = re.search("\\S*****''[[(.+) (.+) (.+)\\S]]''", "*****''[[dogs and cats]]''\n") 
  print test.group(1)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this yourself?

Comment: You say the data you want is in double quotes, but the only double quotes in your text are around the python string. Do you mean two single quotes `''` (rather than double quotes `"`)? Should non-letter characters always be ignored (e.g. the square brackets)?

Comment: Also, you may want to accept answers for your previous questions, to encourage people to help you more!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm still learning the ropes of StackOverflow. Yes, @Austin Henley, I have been working on this for a bit today. So far I have something a long the lines of thistest = re.search("\\S*****''[[(.+) (.+) (.+)\\S]]''", "*****''[[dogs and cats]]''\n")
print test.group(1)

Comment: You should put that code into the question itself (you can also format it properly there!). What happens when you use that code? What do you want to happen differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." Jamie Zawinski

```
data = "*****''[[dogs and cats]]''/n"
start = data.find('[')+2
end = data.find(']')
answer = data[start:end].split()

print answer[0]
print answer[1]
print answer[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight and quote! Thank you @Moshe

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you're looking for, but I will assume you are looking for a regex that parses out one or more space-separated words surrounded by some non-alphanumeric characters.

```
data = "*****''[[dogs and cats]]''/n"

# this pulls out the 'dogs and cats' substring
interior = re.match(r'\W*([\w ]*)\W*', data).group(1)

words = interior.split()

print words
# => ['dogs', 'and', 'cats']
```

This makes a lot of assumptions about your requirements though.  Depending on exactly what you want, regular expressions may not be the best tool.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, this is fairly simple using one extra `split` step:

```
data = "***rubbish**''[[dogs and cats]]''**more rubbish***"
words = re.findall('\[\[(.+?)\]\]', data)[0].split() # 'dogs', 'and', 'cats'
```

One single expression is also possible, but it looks rather confusing:

```
rr = r'''
    (?x)
    (\w+)
    (?=
        (?:
            (?!\[\[)
            .
        )*?
        \]\]
    )
'''
words = re.findall(rr, data) # 'dogs', 'and', 'cats'
```

Comment: the split is a good way to get around it, albeit a little confusing. Thanks @thg435.